# Unpredictable behavior of getAll() method of SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I setup a project with a viewPager with 10 different adapters. And this viewPager is tied to a tabLayout. Titles for the tabs were fetched from a prefilled dataset in sharedPreferences, from index 0-9. So I simply call getAll() and point it to Map and use this map as a source for the pager titles.

What I noticed is that a lot of times getAll() returned null objects after a "certain" index (unpredictably) and sometimes it would work absolutely fine and fetch all values.

I couldn't find any relevant information about this behaviour or what may cause this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!